# How have I incorrectly solved $ dw/dt = 0.2w + 2 $?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When solving for $c$ given the following:

> $ dw/dt = 0.2w + 2 $
>
> $ w(0) = 10 $

The first thing I did was multiply the entire equation by $5$ to get rid of the decimal. After doing that, I computed that $ c = 5ln(20) $. However, according to my textbook, $ c = 5ln(4) $. **Bizarrely, if I solve without multiplying the entire equation by $5$, I get the answer in the textbook.** Can someone tell me where I went wrong? Here's my work:

---

$ dw/dt =0 .2w + 2 $

$ 5dw/dt = w + 10 $

> Let $ u = w + 10 $
>
> $ du/dw = 1 $
>
> $ du = dw $

$ 5du/dt = u $

$ 5\displaystyle\int du/u = \displaystyle\int dt $

$ 5ln(u) = t +c $

$ 5ln(w+10) = t +c $

$ ln(w+10) = (1/5)(t+c) $

$ e^{ln(w+10)} = e^{(1/5)(t+c)} $

$ w+10 = e^{(1/5)(t+c)} $

$ w = e^{(1/5)(t+c)} -10 $

> If $ w(0) = 10 $

$ 10 = e^{(1/5)(0+c)} -10 $

$ 10 = e^{(c/5)} -10 $

$ 20 = e^{(c/5)} $

$ ln(20) = ln(e^{(c/5)}) $

$ ln(20) = c/5 $

$ c = 5ln(20) $

Comment: It depends on what the c constant is in your textbook

Comment: A constant is a constant, but you also have to be careful with the initial conditions. Also, don't worry about multiplying to clear fractions or decimals - you should be comfortable with them and not discriminate against them, metaphorically.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct as well as the textbook. If you solve it without multiplying by $5$ you get equation as $$5e^\left({\frac{t+c}{5}}\right)-10$$ with $c=5ln4$. After elementary manipulation it can be made equal to your equation. Like this

$\begin{align}
w&=5e^{\frac{t}{5}}e^{\frac{c}{5}}-10\\
&=e^\left({\frac{t}{5}}\right)e^\left({\frac{5ln20}{5}}\right)-10\\
&=e^\left({\frac{t+c'}{5}}\right)-10
\end{align}$

Here $c'=5ln20$

Comment: Sorry, but could you extrapolate on the *"elementary manipulation"*? I'm not understanding how $ c=5ln4 $ is equal to $ c=5ln20 $

Comment: Ok! Wait I'll edit.